# Getting the value of a number cell with VBA in Excel

Tags: regex, vba, excel

So I have section columns which look like this:

```
8.01
8.02
8.03
8.04
8.05
8.06
8.07
8.08
8.09
8.10
```

And so on and so forth. I have it set up so that it will always show the trailing zeroes (8.10 and 8.20) but when I use VBA to get the value of the cell it still shows 8.1 and 8.2. I'm using

```
x = Cells.Value
```

but it won't work the way I need it to. I have to keep the column as number for sorting and other reasons so changing the type isn't really an option I don't think. How do I assign a number with a trailing zero to a variable in VBA? Do I need to run a test case with REGEX or something?

Comment: As a side note I can't test for Len since the section number goes into then tens (i.e. 9.09 10.10, 11.01 etc.

Comment: use `x = Cells(1,1).Text` or `x = Format(Cells(1,1).Value,"0.00")`. I suppose that `x` has string type

Comment: How have you declared `x`?

Comment: Can you elaborate why the variable has to keep the trailing zero?

Comment: Numbers are only as accurate as their significant figures. Ie. `8.10` will *always* resolve to `8.1` unless you store the value as a string.

Comment: It's all set now thanks to @simoco! I had to force it to be a number in the code and then convert to string. Finished code looks like x = Format(Cells(1,1).Value, "Standard")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As follow up from comments, this one works:

```
x = Cells(1,1).Text
```

or

```
x = Format(Cells(1,1).Value,"0.00")
```

you can change `"0.00"` to any other format you want, e.g.

```
x = Format(Cells(1,1).Value, "Standard")
```

code above supposed that `x` has `String` type

Comment: Yes it does! Thank's a bunch!